# Looking for an more efficient way to create a 4 directional linked-list

Tags: linked-list

I am trying to create a method that will link all Cell objects set up in a 2D array named CellGrid[,]

My question is: Since most of the code in SetDirection() is so similar, it seem there is a better way to achieve my goal.

(Side note: This is functional but the execution feels "off"  )

```
private void SetDirection()
    {
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < Size * (Size - 1);)//setting all UP pointers
        {
            if ( i == 0 ) { x = 0; y = 1;}//initial setup
            for ( x = 0 ; x < Size ; x++ )
            {
                CellGrid[x,y].SetPointer(CellGrid[x,y-1] , Direction.Up );
                i++;
            }
            y++;
        }
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < Size * (Size - 1);) //setting all DOWN pointers
        {
            if ( i == 0 ) { x = 0; y = 0;}//initial setup
            for ( x = 0 ; x < Size ; x++ )
            {
                CellGrid[x,y].SetPointer(CellGrid[x,y+1], Direction.Down);
                i++;
            }
            y++;
        }
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < Size * (Size - 1);)//setting all LEFT pointers
        {
            if ( i == 0 ) { x = 1; y = 0;}//initial setup
            for ( y = 0 ; y < Size ; y++ )
            {
                CellGrid[x, y].SetPointer( CellGrid[x-1,y], Direction.Left);
                i++;
            }
            x++;
        }
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < Size * (Size - 1);) //setting all RIGHT pointers
        {
            if ( i == 0 ) { x = 0; y = 0;}//initial setup
            for ( y = 0 ; y < Size ; y++ )
            {
                CellGrid[x, y].SetPointer( CellGrid[x+1,y], Direction.Right);
                i++;
            }
            x++;
        }
    }
```

```
public void SetPointer( Cell cellRef ,GridBuilder.Direction dir)
    {
        switch ( dir )
        {
            case GridBuilder.Direction.Up:
                this.Up = cellRef;
                break;
            case GridBuilder.Direction.Down:
                this.Down = cellRef;
                break;
            case GridBuilder.Direction.Left:
                this.Left = cellRef;
                break;
            case GridBuilder.Direction.Right:
                this.Right = cellRef;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use one set of loops to make the links in all four directions. This is based on two ideas:

- When setting a link, immediately set the link in the opposite direction between the same two cells.
- When setting a link, immediately set the link between the two cells that are located in the mirrored positions -- mirrored by the main diagonal (x <--> y).

```java
private void SetDirection() {
    for (int i = 1; i < Size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Size; j++) {
            CellGrid[i, j].SetPointer(CellGrid[i-1, j], Direction.Left);
            CellGrid[i-1, j].SetPointer(CellGrid[i, j], Direction.Right);
            CellGrid[j, i].SetPointer(CellGrid[j, i-1], Direction.Up);
            CellGrid[j, i-1].SetPointer(CellGrid[j, i], Direction.Down);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer along with the clear explanation. Its very clear and helpful.

I am new here, am I making the right steps to show that your answer is one that I needed?